# Quantitative methodology for contrastive pragmatics in corpus-based settings

Tags: corpora, comparative-linguistics, pragmatics, methodology, quantitative-linguistics

I am interested in literature regarding methodology that could be relevant for quantitative research into differences in pragmatic meaning between two 'equivalent' concepts in two languages (in other words: two 'linguistic units' having the same referent, i.e. *dog* in English, and *Hund* in German).

I am specifically speaking about 'conceptual differences in meaning'. For example, an indigenous people living in the far Northern hemisphere could refer to dogs in the context of using them for transport (i.e. dog sled), while sedentary peoples would more often refer to them while implicitly assuming their function as a pet. (Possibly, this is leaning a bit towards semantics as well).

**What are the currently available methods for quantitatively analysing such pragmatic differences, assuming a perfectly annotated corpus for both investigated languages?**

I would like to add that I am especially looking for methodology that assumes 'low-resource languages' (in other words: relatively small sized annotated corpora) and interpretable results (I am aware of relatively large body of available methodology that would not yield 'human-interpretable'-results; many of which involve some sort of abstract encoding of units into, i.e., vector representations).

Inspired by the theory of distributional semantics, I reason that such methods would need to base itself on the *contexts* in which the investigated concepts appear. For my question, this would only regard the contexts that can be observed in the corpora (i.e. surrounding words in a sentence).

Myself, I came up with the idea to count hypernyms of context words: i.e. in the sentence *He sat down onto his dog sled.*, some nested hypernym of *sled* could be something like 'means of transport'; while in the sentence *The dog was sleeping under the table.*, an hypernym of *table* could be 'furniture', indicating a domestic setting in which dogs are seen as pets. Of course, this method would require possibly biased manual annotation or a perfectly annotated corpus of hypernymy-relationships (which could by itself be problematic, due to outdatedness or polysemy-related problems). I am aware of datasets, such as WordNet, for this purpose.

Thank you!

Comment: It's dog sled, not sledge. You might want to look into the concept of co-texts.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I have heard of co-texts and collocation analysis, but I will look into that more. But I assume (and hope) that there is more to this problem than only that.